# How to compute perplexity using KenLM?

Tags: python, nlp, language-model, kenlm, perplexity

Let's say we build a model on this:

```
$ wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/alvations/1c1b388456dc3760ffb487ce950712ac/raw/86cdf7de279a2b9bceeb3adb481e42691d12fbba/something.txt
$ lmplz -o 5 < something.txt > something.arpa
```

From the perplexity formula (https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/languagemodeling.pdf)

Applying the sum of inverse log formula to get the inner variable and then taking the nth root, the perplexity number is unusually small:

```
>>> import kenlm
>>> m = kenlm.Model('something.arpa')

# Sentence seen in data.
>>> s = 'The development of a forward-looking and comprehensive European migration policy,'
>>> list(m.full_scores(s))
[(-0.8502398729324341, 2, False), (-3.0185394287109375, 3, False), (-0.3004383146762848, 4, False), (-1.0249041318893433, 5, False), (-0.6545327305793762, 5, False), (-0.29304179549217224, 5, False), (-0.4497605562210083, 5, False), (-0.49850910902023315, 5, False), (-0.3856896460056305, 5, False), (-0.3572353720664978, 5, False), (-1.7523181438446045, 1, False)]
>>> n = len(s.split())
>>> sum_inv_logs = -1 * sum(score for score, _, _ in m.full_scores(s))
>>> math.pow(sum_inv_logs, 1.0/n)
1.2536033936438895
```

Trying again with a sentence not found in the data:

```
# Sentence not seen in data.
>>> s = 'The European developement of a forward-looking and comphrensive society is doh.'
>>> sum_inv_logs = -1 * sum(score for score, _, _ in m.full_scores(s))
>>> sum_inv_logs
35.59524390101433
>>> n = len(s.split())
>>> math.pow(sum_inv_logs, 1.0/n)
1.383679905428275
```

And trying again with totally out of domain data:

```
>>> s = """On the evening of 5 May 2017, just before the French Presidential Election on 7 May, it was reported that nine gigabytes of Macron's campaign emails had been anonymously posted to Pastebin, a document-sharing site. In a statement on the same evening, Macron's political movement, En Marche!, said: "The En Marche! Movement has been the victim of a massive and co-ordinated hack this evening which has given rise to the diffusion on social media of various internal information"""
>>> sum_inv_logs = -1 * sum(score for score, _, _ in m.full_scores(s))
>>> sum_inv_logs
282.61719834804535
>>> n = len(list(m.full_scores(s)))
>>> n
79
>>> math.pow(sum_inv_logs, 1.0/n)
1.0740582373271952
```

Although, it is expected that the longer sentence has lower perplexity, it's strange that the difference is less than 1.0 and in the range of decimals.

**Is the above the right way to compute perplexity with KenLM? If not, does anyone know how to computer perplexity with the KenLM through the Python API?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/blob/master/python/kenlm.pyx#L182

```
import kenlm

model=kenlm.Model("something.arpa") 
per=model.perplexity("your text sentance")

print(per)
```

Comment: Might not be optimal for all perplexity computation but yes the python wrapper for `kenlm` has the sentence perplexity pre-coded.

Answer (score 3):

The perplexity formula is:

[image]

But that's taking the raw probability, so in code:

```
 import numpy as np
 import kenlm
 m = kenlm.Model('something.arpa')
 # Because the score is in log base 10, so:
 product_inv_prob = np.prod([math.pow(10.0, score) for score, _, _ in m.full_scores(s)])
 n = len(list(m.full_scores(s)))
 perplexity = math.pow(product_inv_prob, 1.0/n)
```

Or using the log (base 10) prob directly:

```
 sum_inv_logprob = -1 * sum(score for score, _, _ in m.full_scores(s))
 n = len(list(m.full_scores(s)))
 perplexity = math.pow(10.0, sum_inv_logs / n)
```

Source: https://www.mail-archive.com/moses-support@mit.edu/msg15341.html

Answer (score 3):

Just want to comment on alvas's answer that

```
sum_inv_logprob = sum(score for score, _, _ in m.full_scores(s))
```

Should actually be:

```
sum_inv_logprob = -1.0 * sum(score for score, _, _ in m.full_scores(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use

```
import numpy as np
import kenlm
m = kenlm.Model('something.arpa')
ppl = m.perplexity('something')
```

Comment: What's the difference with the answer from @Basant Kumar ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44105678/9494790